# What programming language should i learn?

Tags: c#, java, programming-languages, new-operator

I work for a manufacturing company in the configuration dept so i see alot of process related data control stuff passing me by everyday. In the past i have developed some excel vbscript programmes to manage a lot of data items through a GUI and using excel as the backend to store results, but there's only so far you can take that.

I would really like to learn how to create proper databases with GUIs, multiple user logins and workflows for approval etc, but i have no idea where to start.........any advise on desktop applications or web based applications to allow the system to be used over the internet when working abroad, would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Fergie

Answer (score 2):

C# and .net would be a good place to start. C# is fairly easy to learn and visual studios offers a great development environment for it.

Java is also another way you can go. Java is multiplatform and has great functionality for integrating into a web environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a comprehensive solution for desktop apps, web apps and database development, you should definitely look into Visual Studio and .NET. It's the most "cohesive" suite of tools you can use and it sounds like you have some MS programming skills already.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming language per se and it's cost money, but [FileMaker Pro](http://filemaker.com) is great for what you're describing.  It's a RAD tool that creates a database and GUI pretty much in the same development cycle.

We use FileMaker Pro for lot of small business software we write, we also heavily use Java, and FileMaker is at least 10 times easier/faster to build things in.

One final note, FileMaker is cross-platform for Mac and Windows, unlike C# which I see mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

This is *very* subjective, but based on your requirements, I'd go with C#. Both Java and C# let you develop both web and client apps, but C# integrates much more smoothly with Linux and *especially* Windows. Also, Visual Studio has an absolutely phenomenal debugger that will make your life much easier.